# How to be energetic after a 20-30 min siesta (afternoon nap)

Tags: sleep, energy

I sleep at 9pm and wake up at 4am, take a cup of warm water and I will do some simple exercises very slowly, then some house work. At 5am, I run for 30min with the speed 9km/hr (so it is a 4.5km run). I take a shower and I feel very good and energetic.

After a breakfast with high protein, sometimes I will fell a little bit sleepy. But if I go out to have some fresh air, everything is great.

I take the lunch almost between 10:50-11:30am, then a 10min slow walk.

*I take a 20-30min (depending on if I am very tired) siesta at 12pm. When I wake up with some easy exercises, I still feel the body and brain are not so fully awake. And my heart rate is a little fast.*

I think I can wake my body if I run for a while, say 3km. But I don't want to run at 12h30pm or 1pm. Also, it is not convenient to run in the campus. Furthermore, I prefer to run at 5pm or 5:30pm.

*Do you have any idea how to be energetic after a 20-30 min siesta (afternoon nap)?*

Comment: Do you rule out only running, are you looking for other exercises to do?

Comment: Anything other than running which is convenient to do in an office (only me in the office). I tried coffee, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the kind of info you're looking for, but I often take what I call a "caffeine nap". The perfect length of nap for me is 15-20 minutes, so right before I take my nap, I have half a cup of coffee. It takes about 20-30 minutes for the caffeine to hit me, so it doesn't interfere with my napping. Once I wake up, I am totally ready to go because I am rested from the nap and have extra energy from the coffee.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty normal to feel a little tired right after a nap.  However, feeling sleepy consistently and heavily after a nap can very well be other problems.

You seem like you sleep enough (9-4).  I don't know much about your diet, but I would suggest first and foremost [stay hydrated throughout the day](http://www.getfitchimp.com/blog/5-tips-to-consume-more-water/13).  Studies show that proper hydration prevents feeling fatigue, sleepy and increases awareness.

However, it seems like you are looking for a quick workout while you are at work to be energetic after a nap.  I wrote this [blog](http://www.getfitchimp.com/blog/get-fit-at-your-own-desk/12), and you might want to check it out to see if this quick workout is helpful for you.  Let me know your thoughts.